# Import module from parent directory inside dynamically imported module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have files like this:

```
dir
 + main.py
 +--a
 |  +a.py
 |
 +--b
 |  +b.py
 |
 +--c
    +c.py
```

In `main.py` I have

```py
from b import b
funcs = b.loadAllFromC()
# some code which uses funcs
```

in `b.py` I am trying to load all modules inside folder `c` and get function inside each for them to use in `main.py`:

```
import os
import importlib

def loadAllFromC():
    modules = []
    importlib.invalidate_caches()
    for file in os.listdir("./c/"):
        if file.endswith(".py"):
            module = importlib.import_module("c." + file[:-3])
            modules.append(module.getFunc())
    return modules
```

and in `c.py` is something like this:

```
from a import a

def func():
    # code which uses something from a
def getFunc():
    return func
```

But the `module.getFunc()` in `b.py` fails:

```
...
File "... /dir/c/c.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a'
```

When I try `from ..a import a` I get `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`.
How can I use `a.py` from `c.py`?

Comment: Is there any reason not use a package: https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/#package-initialization ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer There is no reason to not use package. I tried to import everything that `c.py` could need (in examle it's `a.py`) from the `__init__.py` and now I can import it from `c.py`. Thanks! :)